# Mock a callback

Tags: java, mockito

I'm trying to test a 3rd party library that works with a callback.

```
Db db;
db.find("param", new DbCallback() {
   public void onComplete(Result r) {
     //my business logic with r
     r.get("name"); //etc
   }
});
```

This is inside class `Foo` which is my test subject. It looks like this:

```
class Foo {

   @Autowired
   Db db;

   void bar() {
    db.find("param", new DbCallback() {
       public void onComplete(Result r) {
           // my business logic with r
           r.get("name"); //etc
       }
    });
  }
}
```

My test so far looks like this:

```
class FooTest {
  @InjectMocks
  Foo foo; // test subject

  @Mock
  Db db; //thing I want to mock

  // initMocks etc. 

  @Test
  void bar() {
    when(db.find( ??? )).then???
    foo.bar();
    // asserts etc. 
  }
}
```

But I'm not entirely sure how to use `when` here.

If it was a "regular" method I would just use

`when(db.find(anyString()).thenReturn(fakeData)`

Comment: does `onComplete` has any side-effects?

Comment: it does, I take the data there and pass it somewhere else...

Comment: wait, I might miss something. Can't you simply do : `Db db = Mockito.mock(Db.class);
        DbCallback callback = Mockito.mock(DbCallback.class);
        Mockito.doNothing().when(callback).onComplete(Mockito.any(Result.class));
        
        Mockito.when(db.find(Mockito.anyString(), callback)).thenReturn(...)`

Comment: @Eugene hmm maybe? I don't know, let me try it

Answer (score 1):

As long as you use Spring components, I highly recommend limiting yourself to mocking or spying beans using specific Spring Test annotations using Mockito through the Spring package `org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito`. A nice example is seen on JavaDoc of [`@MockBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html). Translated to your code sample:

```
@MockBean    // this annotation creates a mock bean in Spring context
Db db;       // thing I want to mock

@Autowired   // injected as usual with the preference of mocked beans dependencies
Foo foo;     // test subject
```

Of course the test-class annotation differs for each version of jUnit used:

- jUnit 4: `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`
- jUnit 5: `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`

---

Back to your question, the `when-then` construct becomes fairly simple. Using static methods of Mockito class you are able to define what object types should be present as method parameters (either "any" value of a type or a specific value).

It also depends whether the method `Db#find` is `void` or has a return type.

- The method has a return type:

  ```
  // the data object doesn't need to be a mock
  DbFindMethodReturnType mockData = new DbFindMethodReturnType(...); 

  Mockito.when(db.find(
              Mockito.eq("params"),            // Mockito.anyString() for any string
              Mockito.any(DbCallback.class)))  // Mockito.any() is also possible
         .thenReturn(mockData)
  ```
- The method is `void`:

  ```
  Mockito.doNothing()
         .when(db)
         .find(Mockito.eq("params"), Mockito.any(DbCallback.class));
  ```